# Excel userform checkboxes null

Tags: excel, checkbox, userform

I have created a userform and added a chekcbox called 'DSSSContact'. I have written some code to check the contents of the userform before saving in the following sub:

```
Private Sub SaveandClose_Click()
```

When the form is initialized the checkbox is set greyed out but ticked - which I think means the value is null. The SavandClose sub code includes the following which I thought would make sure that checkbox is either set to true or false:

```
If DSSSContact = Null Then
MsgBox "DSSS Contact Test"
Exit Sub
End If
```

However when I save and close the form using the save and close command button without having made a selection on the checkbox the form saves the contents without triggering the message box. All the other checks that I have created to verify that textboxes and combo boxes are populated are working fine. I have also added the following code within the same sub:

```
Debug.Print Me.DSSSContact.Value
```

This prints null in the Immediate window

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
If IsNull(DSSSContact.Value) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Check boxes in the forms are True  = checked or False = Unchecked.

```
sub test()
    MsgBox DSSSContact.Value
    If DSSSContact.Value = "False" Then
    MsgBox "DSSS Contact Test"
    Exit Sub
    End If

end sub
```